# Storing Large Models Common Data between Different PHP Pages

Tags: php, asp.net, html

Please tell me how to store common data like an arraylist of Sports Class
which will have different variables in it. I want to access that Arraylist from Vaious pages, so please tell me or send some link so that i will be able to do that.

I am new in PHP Progamming, but done sufficient amount of Web Programming in .Net.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't really stateful so you will load the class on each page you visit.  To store information in an instantiated class filled with data, you can either just store the data in the $_SESSION superglobal or serialize the data and then store it in a file.

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: you can not store large amount of data in session. So its better to store serialized data in a file